# Concatenate a string with an incrementing number

Tags: python, string

Here is my code:

```
n = 2
campaign_img = soup.find('div', class_="campaign-img-contain")
name = str(n) + '-' + campaign_name
campaign_pic = request.urlretrieve(campaign_img.img['src'], folder + name + '.png')
print(campaign_pic)
n = n + 1
```

I want this:

2-campaign_name

3-campaign_name

4-campaign_name

Result:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

What is the best possible solution?

Comment: `name = str(n) + '-' + campaign_name`; You cannot concatenate strings and integers. So convert the `int` to `str`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I have tried this one but n is not going to be increment after one iteration

Comment: @schwobaseggl i want increment in n as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you can’t concatenate an integer and a string together into another string. You want **casting**. To cast an integer to a string in Python, use the built-in `str` function.

Replace the line `name= n + '-' + campaign_name` with `name = str(n) + '-' + campaign_name`.

More on casting (W3Schools): *[Python Casting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp)*

Comment: I tried this one but i need increment in n after one iteration. In this way, only 2-campaign_name is print always.

Comment: How are you iterating? Is part of this code in a loop? If so you'll need to make sure the n = 2 is before the start of the loop.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the integer as a string:

```
name = str(n) + '-' + campaign_name
```

Comment: I tried this one but i need increment in n after one iteration. In this way, only 2-campaign_name is print always.

Answer (score 0):

Or, use string formatting

```
name = f"{n}-{campaign_name}"
```

Comment: "[f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions)"?